# How to create a table of percentage changes in R?

Tags: r

I have a table df that looks like this (with many more columns and many more rows):

[image]

I want to create a new table df2 in which each cell in the red box is replaced by percentage change from the value for the previous date (with the top row obviously displaying NA). For example the bottom right cell in the new table should read -.0188

Is there a function (base or from some package) that can do this? If so, how can I use it?

Comment: Please don't post images of data, instead use `dput` to provide a short sample. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using some made up data and `tidyverse` functions. The key thing here is `dplyr::lag`, which lets you reference the previous value in a data frame. Note that the selection `vars(-day)` selects all the columns except `day`, and the use of `funs(pct_change = )` creates new columns with the original name prepended to `pct_change`. Inside `funs`, the `.` refers to a value in that column, so we can directly calculate the proportional change by dividing by the previous value and subtracting 1.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
tbl <- tibble(
  day = 1:4,
  col1 = rnorm(4, mean = 10),
  col2 = rnorm(4, mean = 10)
)

tbl %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(-day),
    .funs = funs(pct_change = (. / lag(.)) - 1)
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>     day  col1  col2 col1_pct_change col2_pct_change
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1     1  9.50 10.1          NA              NA     
#> 2     2 10.1  10.3           0.0667          0.0199
#> 3     3  9.92  9.42         -0.0208         -0.0873
#> 4     4 10.9  10.7           0.0973          0.138
```

Created on 2018-04-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` based solution can be as:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

#Convert Date column to of type Date/POSIXct and order on that column  
DT[,Date:=ymd(Date)][
        order(Date),c(.(Date = Date), lapply(.SD,function(x)(x/lag(x) - 1))),.SDcols=2:4]

#          Date        AEDUSD       AUDUSD       CADUSD
# 1: 2008-03-17            NA           NA           NA
# 2: 2008-03-18  0.0000000000 -0.021097496 -0.006626446
# 3: 2008-03-19  0.0000000000  0.009361054  0.001294305
# 4: 2008-03-20 -0.0003671072 -0.006578238 -0.009645023
# 5: 2008-03-24  0.0000000000 -0.026378637 -0.018775100
```

**Data:**

```
DT = data.table(Date = c("2008-03-17","2008-03-18","2008-03-19","2008-03-20","2008-03-24"),
           AEDUSD = c(0.2724, 0.2724, 0.2724, 0.2723, 0.2723),
           AUDUSD = c(0.9385, 0.9187, 0.9273, 0.9212, 0.8969),
           CADUSD = c(1.0111, 1.0044, 1.0057, 0.9960, 0.9773))
```